# Is it possible to target entities with potion effects through any command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was screwing around and attempting to make a mechanism where if a player shoots an entity with a special arrow (that gives a potion effect as a marker), and then activates another command block, it would kill all entities with that potion effect. After searching extensively, I couldn't find any NBT selector that I could use to kill entities with a potion effect, and there most certainly was not any other argument after `@e[`. Is there any NBT selector to target it, or any other way that I overlooked?

I found an old answer suggesting scoreboard functions, but it seems to be outdated and have the same issue (commands not being able to discriminate/select entities based on active effects, as far as I can find).

Answer (score 2):

The NBT tag you're looking for is `ActiveEffects`. For example, if you shoot a mob with a spectral arrow, it gets this NBT tag:

```
ActiveEffects:[{Id:24b,Duration:200,Amplifier:0b,Ambient:0b,ShowParticles:1b,ShowIcon:1b}]
```

So you can target every mob with the glowing effect like this:

```
@e[nbt={ActiveEffects:[{Id:24b}]}]
```

Unlike when setting NBT, you have to be exact when reading NBT, so you need the `b`.

The number is the numerical [effect ID](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Status_effect#Summary_of_effects) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Status_effect&oldid=1286871#Summary_of_effects)).

Comment: I couldn't find it after like 2 hours yesterday, thank you so much!

Comment: If it helped you, you can indicate that using the checkmark icon. It means something like "question is solved by this".